# Read/Write syscall in FUSE

Tags: linux, system-calls, fuse

In context of a FUSE filesystem I'm wondering whether the buffer of a read/write syscall (see `buf` at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html & https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is allocated in the user space or the kernel space when calling the FUSE.

Because of the behaviour on the pipe syscall (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)

> Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel
> until it is read from the read end of the pipe.

I'm assuming that the buffer is allocated in the kernel space.

Nevertheless I'm searching for sources.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/filesystems/fuse.html

Comment: Could you please link to the section where this could be useful?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/filesystems/fuse.html#kernel-userspace-interface